# Retrieve image from database and set it to background-image property css in asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how I can set the picture that I uploaded to SQL Server, and set it to `background-image` style in div. I know that url function in css only accept the path to the image. Is there any workaround that can config for the property to accept the image file directly from database?

```
<div class="item-2">
    <a href="@Url.Action("Details", new { id = item.id })" class="card">
    @{ 
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.img);
        var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);

        <div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('@imgsrc');"></div>
        <article>
            <h1>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</h1>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.info)</p>
            <span>Major</span>
        </article>
    }
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an action that returns image buffer like:

```
return File(imageBuffer, "image/jpeg");
```

and put action address in src attribute of img tag

Comment: But then how would i set it to css background-image property if i use img tag. i want to be able to set background image for a div